# How to finish the Ads_Fullscreen Activity in 8 seconds and lunch the MainActivity after wards?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

Two situation for Splash Screen

1. if ads is enable then Splash Screen time will be 2 seconds and Ads_Fullscreen time will be 8 seconds then final Main Activity will come.
2. if ads is not enable then Splash Screen time will be 5 seconds and then Main Activity will come.

This is code for splash screen

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          Intent i;
          if (prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()){
              i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,WelcomeActivity.class);
              prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
          }else if(bn_bstatus.equals("enable")) {
              i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,Ads_Fullscreen.class);

          }else{
              i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
          }
          startActivity(i);
          finish();
      }
  },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set default `SPLASH_TIME_OUT` as `5000` milliseconds.

```
public final int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;
```

> For SplashScreen Activity

```
final Intent intent;
if (ads.enable()) {
    intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
    prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
} else if (bn_bstatus.equals("enable")) {
    intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Ads_Fullscreen.class);
    SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;
} else {
    intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
}
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

> For Ads_Fullscreen Activity

```
SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 8000;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // start MainActivity
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

Comment: Thanks @Dhruv you are the best and answer worked like charm!