# Handle null exception in RecyclerView from PHP URL

Tags: java, php, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to handle this null exception in RecyclerView from PHP URL. I want it to show a Toast message if a null exception occurs: `No Result Found`.

null exception:

[image: null exception]

Code

```java
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(uarray);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject p = array.getJSONObject(i);
                Category_Movie item = new Category_Movie(
                    p.getInt("id"), 
                    p.getString("mTitle"), 
                    p.getString("mDesc"), 
                    p.getInt("mYear"), 
                );
                listItems.add(item);
            }
            mAdapter = new CategoryListAll_Adapter(listItems, getActivity());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        } catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
},

new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: You can show toast message inside your catch method

Comment: Check `jsonObject.has(uarray)` before parsing `JSONObject` into `JSONArray`.

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject This error i have recieved now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Create one method to validate your JSONObject

```
public boolean isJSONValid(String jsonStr) {
    try {
        new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Try to edit following code:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (isJSONValid(response)) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(uarray);
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject p = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        Category_Movie item = new Category_Movie(
                                p.getInt("id"),
                                p.getString("mTitle"),
                                p.getString("mDesc"),
                                p.getInt("mYear"),
                                );
                        listItems.add(item);
                    }
                    mAdapter = new CategoryListAll_Adapter(listItems, getActivity());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // your Toast Message
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject This is error i have received in logcat

Comment: can u help me with this one as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258163/how-to-finish-the-ads-fullscreen-activity-in-8-seconds-and-lunch-the-mainactivit

Answer (score 0):

Returning early ordinary is way to go ...

therefore I'd compare to the known `String` value of `null`, in case of no results,

before checking if it possibly could be valid `JSON` (which can already be out-ruled):

```
if(! response.equals("null")) {
   try ...
}
```

---

or improve statement `e.printStackTrace()` and handle that `JSONException` accordingly:

```
try {
    ...
} catch(JSONException e) {
    if(response.equals("null")) {
        /* assume no results */
    } else {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

While having access to the `PHP` code ...better always return a *parse-able* `JSON` response:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
die(json_encode((object) array(
    "success" => false,
    "error" => "no results"
)));
```

... when the client expects `application/json` instead of `text/plain`.